# OutOfMemoryException while downloading files in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

While i am trying to download the large files ( of size >170 MB ) from windows mobile application i am getting this exception

An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Additional information: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.

The strange thing is i am getting the exception only for few files. This is the code i used to download the file

```
       hpubDownloader = new WebClient();
        hpubDownloader.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
           //process response
        };
        hpubDownloader.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            int value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            //show progress percentage , and it shows till 98 % after that it goes to exception App_Unhandled exception
        };
        hpubDownloader.OpenReadAsync(url);
```

What might be the reaosn for this ? I am not getting any other details about exception and even i tried to put Try- catch block in webclient download code , but  thats also not firing . What might be the possible reasons?

Comment: there is some memory limit for a particular app ,if your file is >170MB means your application uses all allotted memory and there is no more space to save our remaining file.

Comment: follow below posted artical

Comment: What's the purpose of downloading such large files to memory? Is it really needed? It's a Phone App.

Answer (score 3):

Follow this MSDN article for more information - [App memory limits for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681682%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Memorylimitbyapptype)

[image: MemoryLimits]

Comment: @Romasz Is there any way to override this limitation? Example if my phone memory is 512 MB , is any way to download a file of size 170 MB

Comment: @JMat Surely you can download such a file directly to IsolatedStorage, but if you want to put that into Memory - there can be a problem. I doubt that there is a way to override the limits.

Comment: @JMat Surely you could increase memory but that required amount of memory must be available in your device....for more details you could follow above posted link in this post

Comment: @Pradeep What i can see is  How to disable features in apps for lower-memory phones. But i did'nt see any explanation on how to do the memory limit actions

Comment: @Romasz How can i do that (Save directly to isolated storage - without saving to memory) ? I posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671157/save-to-isolated-storage-directly-in-wp8